# Windows 11 Home: Language: "right-click for more options" doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-11, input-languages

I see the message below, but right-clicking doesn't do anything. What should I do to get this to work (or get access to these options)?

[image]

Using Windows 11 Home, Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621.

Comment: Can you just go to/from Windows Settings instead?

Comment: @TomYan: I don't know/can't find the relevant "more options". Which is why I'm asking this question. (I want to use Pinyin input with Traditional Chinese. Googling, some websites suggested I could do this by going to these "more options".)

Comment: I think that "More options" relates to *Settings > Time & Language > Language*, click on your keyboard and press the Options button. Your choice of the language flavor is also important - see [Counterintuitive traditional Chinese input on Windows](https://fabian-voith.de/2020/10/26/counterintuitive-traditional-chinese-input-on-windows/).

Comment: @harrymc Great thanks, that page didn't give me exactly what I wanted but following the clues there I managed to find what I wanted.

Comment: Normally, when someone gives you the right answer, you invite that person to put up the answer which you then mark as accepted, adding a comment if required.

Comment: Especially when you have posted a bounty.

Comment: @harrymc: Mm lol OK if you care so much about the points, go ahead and copy paste my answer and post it as an answer. I'll then accept it as an answer and give you the bounty.

Comment: (I actually didn't consider my "answer" below to be a good or proper answer to my question above, which was about how I can get the right click to work and in particular to get to the "more options" dialog. In my "answer" below, I merely wanted to share some details of what I did to get what I was looking for, in case anyone else on the internet was looking for the same information. I didn't imagine that any user here would be so obsessed with points as to be offended by my posting of such details.)

Comment: You have a strange way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Settings > Time & language > Language & region
2. Next to the relevant language, click the "...", then click "Language options"
3. Under "Keyboards", next to the relevant "Input method editor" (IME), click the "...", then click "Keyboard options"

I believe these are the "more options".

For example in my case I could then also click on "General", where I could under "Choose a character set" switch to "Traditional Chinese".